# Take all files and folders from all branches in Git

Tags: git

I would like to create a script for Git that takes all folders from all branches in Git and put it into the master branch.
My starting point is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for branch in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/heads/); do
    git log --oneline "$branch"
done
```

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. One doesn't "put folders in branches" in git. Do you want to *merge* all branches into master?

Comment: Merge can be one of the possible solutions. Can you show me please how should I do it? Thank you!

Comment: But I still don't get what the end goal is, so sugesting a solution is clearly premature. Get all changes from feature branches to have them all integrated into the master version? If so, yes, merge all of them. This is standard git process, I'd suggest browsing any of the many docs/tutorials out there for this. If you don't know where to start, try the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git/info), it's an excellent base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# CHANGE REPOSITORY LINK!!!
git clone https://github.com/{owner}/docs_repo_for_script_test
mkdir content
# CHANGE REPOSITORY NAME AT THE LINE BELOW!!!
cd docs_repo_for_script_test

for BRANCH in $(git branch -a | grep remotes/origin | grep -v HEAD) ;
do
    FOLDER="../content/$(cut -d'/' -f3 <<<"$BRANCH")"
    echo branch: !$BRANCH!
    echo folder: !$FOLDER!
    git checkout $BRANCH
    mkdir $FOLDER
    cp -r * $FOLDER
done
```